# Show first section of an article (HTML/ JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I only show the first section of the article with class `.class1`. I hide all elements first and only the first section of the article with class `.class1` shoud be shown. I thought about something with `:firstChild` but im very unexperienced and I have no idea how to solve that problem.

```
<article class="x class1">
    <section>
        <p>1</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>1</p>
    </section>
</article>
<article class="x class2">
    <section>
        <p>2</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>2</p>
    </section>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".x").hide()

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) like this:

```js
$(".x").not(".class1").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="x class1">
    <section>
        <p>1</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>1</p>
    </section>
</article>
<article class="x class2">
    <section>
        <p>2</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>2</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

Nope! to show only the first section of the class1 element you can use this:

```js
$(".x section").not(":eq(0)").hide(); //hides all the section inside the .x class, except the first
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="x class1">
    <section>
        <p>1</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>2</p>
    </section>
</article>
<article class="x class2">
    <section>
        <p>3</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>4</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

thanks @pawel!

Comment: "only the first section of the article with class "class1" shoud be shown" so it's a partial solution, but hiding the non-first sections can be worket out from this example.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [example](http://api.jquery.com/first/) it should help you out.

You can just hide them all like you are doing and just use first like you are thinking to show the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Only with CSS:

```
article {
   display: none;
}

article[class*="class1"] {
   display: inherit;
}

article[class*="class1"] section:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

[Live example on the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juxsnvn4/2/)

**Compatibility**

- IE7+
- Firefox
- Chrome
- Safari
- Opera

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(".x:not(.class1)").hide();
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(".x > section").not(":first").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific sitation I'd use

```
$('article + article, section + section').hide();
```

it'll hide every `<article>` that's after another `<article>` (so not the first one), and similarly with `<section>`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/ku5tnaeL/